# How to fix sed: no previous regular expression error in a sc

Tags: bash, shell, nginx, sed, environment-variables

Hi I'm running the line:

```
sudo sed -i "s/${SERVER_ENVIRONMENT}/$SERVER_ENVIRONMENT/" /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf
```

in a bash script.

I want to replace the string ${SERVER_ENVIRONMENT} with the value of the environment variable "$SERVER_ENVIRONMENT", which is stored in /etc/environment, but when I run the bash script I'm getting this error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression

Does anyone know how I fix this error? Cheers

Comment: Prefix your command with `echo` and a space.

Answer (score 0):

sed doesn't understand literal strings, only regexps and backslash-enabled replacement text, see [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) for details.

I'd use awk for this since it does let you use literal strings:

```
awk -i inplace '
    BEGIN { old="${SERVER_ENVIRONMENT}"; new=ENVIRON["SERVER_ENVIRONMENT"] }
    s=index($0,old) { $0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old)) }
1' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf
```

the above will work no matter which characters `$SERVER_ENVIRONMENT` contains.

To do "inplace" editing it's using `awk -i inplace '...' file` with GNU awk just like you can do `sed -i '...' file` with GNU sed.

Since your variable name is all-upper-case I assume it's exported (see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) for why I say that) but if not then set it to itself on the command line so you don't have to export it for it to be available in `ENVIRON[]`:

```
SERVER_ENVIRONMENT="$SERVER_ENVIRONMENT" awk -i inplace '...' file
```